# Show index rather than CIF at x axis

Tags: tableau-api

So I'm struggling with this really simple thing: I have a bar Chart where each bar Shows the Revenue for every Client. Each bar has a Label that shows the customer id. Instead I would like to Show a simple index from 1 to the number of columns. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you supply a sample workbook?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could achieve this by creating a calculated field to index the bars and then use this as your axis.

1. So if you create a calculated field(Analysis->Create Calculated Field). Call this calculated field "Index" and in the the body add the code:

   ```
    index()
   ```

Click "Okay" and this will appear in your measures.

2. Right click the new index calculated field in the measures window and select "convert to discrete".
3. Drag this new field on to your rows shelf.
4. You should now have 2 values against each bar, client ID and index number. Right click the client ID pill in the rows shelf and uncheck the option "show headers"

You should now only have the index number showing for each bar.

Comment: It works, although now the view runs very slowly. An alternative solution I found was to replace the bars label with the index. This way the index appears on top of each bar rather than at the bottom (x axis).